# Reuse of Extbase Partials for Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, typo3, fluid, extbase

I didn't find a Example how to use a fluid partial in a extbase controller to reuse it for an ajax request/response.

Something like the Tag f:render partial=""  but in a controller to return the html in a json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$this->templateView = $this->objectManager->create('Tx_Fluid_View_TemplateView');
$res = t3lib_extMgm::extPath($this->controllerContext->getRequest()->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/Private/';
$this->templateView->setLayoutRootPath($res);
$this->templateView->setPartialRootPath($res . 'Partials/');
$this->templateView->setRenderingContext($this->objectManager->create('Tx_Fluid_Core_Rendering_RenderingContext'));
$this->templateView->setControllerContext($this->controllerContext);

$partial = $this->templateView->renderPartial($partialName, Null, $data);
```

But the only Problem is the setRenderingContext method doesn't set the default RenderingContext correct, i must modify the method.